# Complex type deduction from function template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

I have another C++ template question. I am a lazy guy, so I try to not specify template arguments if possible. Now I have a function

```
template< typename EasyLookingObject >
void myfunct( EasyLookingObject& obj ) {
  //do something with obj
}
```

Now, EasyLookingObject is in fact a

```
boost::ptr_list< A< STDContainer::<TargetType*> > >
```

In order to work with obj, I need to know the types of STDContainer and TargetType. Can you help me to get these types?

Problem 1: EasyLookingObject::value_type does give me a pointer type. How do I deduce the full type from it and use it within a typedef?

The same probably applies to the STDContainer::value_type issue.

Answer (score 2):

Removing the pointer is trivial using partial specialisation:

```
template <typename T>
struct remove_ptr {
    typedef T type;
};

template <typename T>
struct remove_ptr<T*> : remove_ptr<T> { };
```

(I’m sure Boost also has something like this.)

Putting it all together:

```
typedef typename remove_ptr<typename EasyLookingObject::value_type>::type a_t;
typedef typename a_t::container_type container_t;
typedef typename remove_ptr<typename container_t::value_type>::type target_t;
```

Comment: Boost.TypeTraits has `remove_pointer`: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/remove_pointer.html

Comment: There's `std::remove_pointer` in C++11 (or in TR1 I suppose).

Comment: A is a custom class and I can modify it to contain the correct typedefs for the needed types.

Comment: @fungs Well, then you should have all the necessary parts. – Or is something missing?

Comment: Nope, I guess this is it. I will try it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you really can't infer the correct types from class typedefs (which I doubt, double check the documentation), the you can specify the template parameters a bit more explicitly:

```
template <template <typename...> class Container, typename T, typename ...Args>
void myfunc(const Container<T*, Args...> & c)
{
  // ...
}
```

If you don't have variadic templates, you'll have to specify as many arguments as your container takes, or specify default arguments if you only want the template to match those. Here's a defaulting version that works for two-parameter containers:

```
template <template <typename A, typename = std::allocator<A> > class Container,
          typename T>
void myfunc(const Container<T*> & c);
```

This will only match `Container<T*, std::allocator<T*>>`. Here's a general version for two-parameter containers:

```
template <template <typename , typename> class Container,
          typename T1, typename T2>
void myfunc(const Container<T1*, T2> & c);
```

---

Concretely, your function should be a variation of this:

```
template <template <typename> class Container, typename T>
void myfunc(const boost::ptr_list<A<Container::<T*> > > &);
```

Comment: sorry, can you give the template parameter line for my above example? I tried to do this but failed... sorry.

Comment: I added the code, but Konrad's suggestion to just apply `remove_pointer` to the value type is much better.

Comment: you might be right, but I like things to be explicit: much easiert to understand the code.

I tried to compile my code using this but it gives me errors:

    expected `class' before 'Container'/
    template argument 1 is invalid

Comment: Ohh, sorry, that was a bug on my part - fixed!

Comment: I was smart enough to correct this by myself, but it still gives error in the compiler: error: template argument 1 is invalid

Comment: Right... It seems that you cannot cheat, you have to provide the full set of template arguments, or add their defaults to the inner template. If you can, you should prefer the variadic version, but I'll modify the non-variadic version to work with the default vector and I'll add a version with explicit parameters. If you go with the non-variadic version, you'll have to provide one, two, three, and four-argument versions at least (think `unordered_set`).

Comment: thx, at this point only the remove_ptr functionality does what I intend to. I had a working version with explicit type arguments working here, but I wanted it to detect the types on its own.

Comment: That definitely sounds more elegant that this explicit mess here - as I said, if you can get the type from the container directly, that's by far preferable.

Answer (score 0):

> Problem 1: EasyLookingObject::value_type does give me a pointer type. How do I deduce the full type from it and use it within a typedef?

You probably don't need to extract the typedefs.

Just pass every extracted item to another overloaded function. Use an extractor function akin to [`boost::get_pointer()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/boost/get_pointer.hpp) to extract a pointer from a reference, or a plain or smart pointer.

```
template<class Container>
void do_something_item(Item* item); // overload for different types as necessary

template<class Container>
void do_something(Container& c) {
    for(typename Container::iterator i(c.begin()), j(c.end()); i != j; ++i) {
        using boost::get_pointer; 
        do_something_item(get_pointer(*i)); // use ADL to find get_pointer() overload
    }
}
```

Comment: This is nice but AFAIK it does not work to create named variables of the given type. For this I would have to use the suggested boost::remove_pointer functionality.